# Sql select columns using concat variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen similar questions but nothing quite exact to what I need.  I have a rolling 12 month table with columns PL0 thru PL12.  PL0 = current month, PL1 = next month, etc.  I'm trying to set up results that are for a calendar year Jan - Dec that will select PL0 into the current month, PL1 into the next month, etc. Prior months should return 0.  I need to be able to dynamically select the column based on a calculation using the month number.

This is what I want to do but I know it's not right :)

```
CASE WHEN 1-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',1-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS JanPL
CASE WHEN 2-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',2-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS FebPL
CASE WHEN 3-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',3-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS MarPL
CASE WHEN 4-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',4-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS AprPL
CASE WHEN 5-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',5-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS MayPL
CASE WHEN 6-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',6-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS JunPL
CASE WHEN 7-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',7-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS JulPL
CASE WHEN 8-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',8-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS AugPL
CASE WHEN 9-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',9-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS SepPL
CASE WHEN 10-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',10-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS OctPL
CASE WHEN 11-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',11-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS NovPL
CASE WHEN 12-MONTH(GETDATE())<0 THEN 0 ELSE SELECT CONCAT('PL',12-MONTH(GETDATE())) END AS DecPL
```

So in Jan, the results should be:

```
JanPL     |FebPL   |MarPL   |AprPL   |MayPL   |JunPL   |JulPL   |AugPL   |SepPL   |OctPL   |NovPL    |DecPL

PL0 data|PL1 data|PL2 data|PL3 data|PL4 data|PL5 data|PL6 data|PL7 data|PL8 data|PL9 data|PL10 data|PL11 data
```

And in Sept, the results should be:

```
JanPL---|FebPL |MarPL |AprPL |MayPL |JunPL |JulPL |AugPL |SepPL   |OctPL   |NovPL   |DecPL   |
0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      PL0 data|PL1 data|Pl2 data|PL3 data|
```

How can I select the column based on the defined concat string?

Thanks in advance for any help / insight.

Comment: You should fix your data design rather than go this route. Every month should be stored on a separate *row* rather than as a column.

Answer (score 0):

You're kinda on the right track, but with "plain" SQL, you can't generate column names dynamically as you're trying to do in your example. For that you would need to resort to SQL "programming" and create a stored procedure, which (I imagine) is not in the scope of what you're attempting to do here.

So I've adapted/extended your approach as below which I've tested with example data as shown at this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=282c94bb966a6737a0ba414bbbd58c12).  It's not exactly concise or pretty (!), although it has a certain symmetry to it and it seems to do what you've asked for.

```
WITH myMonth(mm) AS (SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())),
myData(PL0, PL1, PL2, PL3, PL4, PL5, PL6, PL7, PL8, PL9, PL10, PL11) AS
(SELECT 100, 220, 150, 60, 230, 40, 90, 120, 30, 50, 145, 210)
SELECT
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS JanPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL1  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS FebPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL2  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL1  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS MarPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL3  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL2  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS AprPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL4  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL3  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS MayPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL5  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL4  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL3 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 6 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS JunPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL6  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL5  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL4 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL3 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 6 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 7 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS JulPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL7  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL6  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL5 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL4 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL3 WHEN mm = 6 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 7 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 8 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS AugPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL8  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL7  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL6 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL5 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL4 WHEN mm = 6 THEN PL3 WHEN mm = 7 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 8 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 9 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS SepPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL9  WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL8  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL7 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL6 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL5 WHEN mm = 6 THEN PL4 WHEN mm = 7 THEN PL3 WHEN mm = 8 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 9 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 10 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS OctPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL10 WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL9  WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL8 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL7 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL6 WHEN mm = 6 THEN PL5 WHEN mm = 7 THEN PL4 WHEN mm = 8 THEN PL3 WHEN mm = 9 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 10 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 11 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS NovPL,
CASE WHEN mm = 1 THEN PL11 WHEN mm = 2 THEN PL10 WHEN mm = 3 THEN PL9 WHEN mm = 4 THEN PL8 WHEN mm = 5 THEN PL7 WHEN mm = 6 THEN PL6 WHEN mm = 7 THEN PL5 WHEN mm = 8 THEN PL4 WHEN mm = 9 THEN PL3 WHEN mm = 10 THEN PL2 WHEN mm = 11 THEN PL1 WHEN mm = 12 THEN PL0 ELSE 0 END AS DecPL
FROM myData, myMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to move this logic to the application code where programming language is more suitable for such things.

There are only 12 months and 12 possible cases (different current months) and alternative approach would to be to "hardcode" all cases into separate table and join it to the result.

```
DECLARE @Months AS TABLE (CurrentMonth INT
    , Jan VARCHAR(10)
    , Feb VARCHAR(10)
    , Mar VARCHAR(10)
    , Apr VARCHAR(10)
    , May VARCHAR(10)
    , Jun VARCHAR(10)
    , Jul VARCHAR(10)
    , Aug VARCHAR(10)
    , Sep VARCHAR(10)
    , Oct VARCHAR(10)
    , Nov VARCHAR(10)
    , Dec VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @Months VALUES
(1, 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4', 'PL5', 'PL6', 'PL7', 'PL8', 'PL9', 'PL10', 'PL11'),
(2, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4', 'PL5', 'PL6', 'PL7', 'PL8', 'PL9', 'PL10'),
(3, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4', 'PL5', 'PL6', 'PL7', 'PL8', 'PL9'),
(4, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4', 'PL5', 'PL6', 'PL7', 'PL8'),
(5, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4', 'PL5', 'PL6', 'PL7'),
(6, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4', 'PL5', 'PL6'),
(7, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4', 'PL5'),
(8, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3', 'PL4'),
(9, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2', 'PL3'),
(10, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1', 'PL2'),
(11, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL1'),
(12, 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0', 'PL0');
```

Usage

```
SELECT m.Jan + ' ' + t.JanPL
    , m.Feb + ' ' + t.FebPL
    , m.Mar + ' ' + t.MarPL
    , m.Apr + ' ' + t.AprPL
    , m.May + ' ' + t.MayPL
    , m.Jun + ' ' + t.JunPL
    , m.Jul + ' ' + t.JulPL
    , m.Aug + ' ' + t.AugPL
    , m.Sep + ' ' + t.SepPL
    , m.Oct + ' ' + t.OctPL
    , m.Nov + ' ' + t.NovPL
    , m.Dec + ' ' + t.DecPL
FROM YourTable t
    INNER JOIN @Months m ON m.CurrentMonth = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Result for September:

```
'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL0 d', 'PL1 d', 'PL2 d', 'PL3 d'
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of shifting operation is a bit tricky in SQL.  One option is to unpivot the months that you have and assign a real date to them.  This is easy using `apply`.  Then reaggregate based on the date.

Then, you can aggregate with the logic you want:

- You want dates only from the current year.
- You want dates before the current month to be `NULL`ed out.
- You want the "pl" values to be in the appropriate month column.

This can be combined into a query like this:

```
select t.*, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(case when month(getdate()) = 1 and month(v.yyyymm) = 1 then v.pl end) as jan,
             max(case when month(getdate()) <= 2 and month(v.yyyymm) = 2 then v.pl end) as feb,
             max(case when month(getdate()) <= 3 and month(v.yyyymm) = 3 then v.pl end) as mar,
            . . .  
      from (values (datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))
           ) d(cur_yyyymm) cross apply
           (values (pl0, dateadd(month, 0, d.cur_yyyymm)),
                   (pl1, dateadd(month, 1, d.cur_yyyymm)),
                   (pl2, dateadd(month, 2, d.cur_yyyymm)),
                   . . . 
                   (pl12, dateadd(month, 12, d.cur_yyyymm))
           ) v(pl, yyyymm)
       where year(v.yyyymm) = year(getdate())
    ) v;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4c6507091f0583df2829a8ad66fd9ac8) is a db<>fiddle.